# EF Core filtered include. Is using a HashSet with OrderBy problematic?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

With EF Core 5 we can filter and order an Include query:

```
var blogsWithOrderedPosts = await context.Blogs.
    Include(b => b.Posts.OrderBy(p => p.PublishDate)).ToListAsync();
```

However, the default collection used for child entities is a HashSet, which the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.hashset-1?view=net-5.0#remarks) says is unordered.

```
public class Blog
{
    public Blog()
    {
        Posts = new HashSet<Post>();
    }

    // ...

    public virtual ICollection<Post> Posts { get; set;}
}
```

My question is, do we need to use a different collection (e.g. List or SortedSet) when ordering an include? I tested out adding objects to a HashSet and using a foreach to enumerate them and they all came out in order, but this isn't guaranteed behavior is it? My followup questions is, if we change the collection, what impact does that have on performance?

Comment: Why do you want to change it? A hash set only guarantees the key and the uniqueness of the objects, not the order. A `HashSet` does preserve the insertion order.

Comment: In your case, expected behaviour is 'guaranteed' by Order By clause. Of course for pre 'sorted' collection it should be faster, but I wouldn't expect that from database.(most cases)

Comment: `but this isn't guaranteed behavior is it?` Correct. It is not guaranteed.

Comment: @ShimmyWeitzhandler `A HashSet does preserve the insertion order.` It _explicitly_ **does not** guarantee that. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.hashset-1?view=net-5.0#remarks

Comment: @mjwillis looks like you're right.